# EditText with custom background and drawable problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing a layout for login screen. Inside login screen I'm adding custom background and drawable to the EditText. It is displaying correctly on android studio preview but when i run it on my test device **LG G4**, everything messes up.

**Android Studio Preview**

[image: Android Studio Preview]

**On Test Device (LG G4)**

[image: On Test Device]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_funhouse_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_brand"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:text="FUN HOUSE"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="LOG IN"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_brand" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_login_et_bg"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_username"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_login_et_bg"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_username" />


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_login_et_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#AAAAAA" />
 </shape>
```

ic_username.xml and ic_password.xml both are same just icon is different

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:height="60dp"
    android:width="50dp"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#5E5E5E"/>
        <corners android:topRightRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_login_square_arrow_button_outline"/>
 </layer-list>
```

Comment: Try adding a drawable padding to your edittext. Maybe your image is to big and therefore the layout gets messed up.
android:drawablePadding="2dp"

Comment: Make sure the size of `ic_login_square_arrow_button_outline` is also 24dp by 24dp.

Comment: Simply have your own mobile  device

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your preview is not the same as in real device is because **you are using fixed sizes on your views**, different phones got different screen size and when you are using fixed size like `android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"` it may work for your current screen tested but will not be responsive to all screen sizes.

---

### How to fix:

If you are already using `ConsraintLayout` you can solve this by using those attributes together with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html):

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.xx"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.yy"
```

This will tell your views to be exactly `xx%` of the screen height and width ad it will make your layout responsive to all screen sizes.

---

**Here is an example of your wanted layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Bonus** - If you want o make your text size responsive as well you can use [sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)